# TFS 2013 Reporting URLs containing computername not accessible

Tags: tfs, reporting, tfsbuild

I have installed and configured TFS 2013.
The TFS Administration Console shows in the Reporting section the following urls:

Reporting Server: http://COMPUTERNAME:80/ReportServer_STANDARD2014

Reporting Manager: http://COMPUTERNAME:80/Report_STANDARD2014

but in the IIS Manager, I do not have a web with the name "COMPUTERNAME". The URL ist inaccessible. But I cannot change it to the Machines IP Address, I get an error message, with not found and so on.
Why tfs uses such inaccessible URLS. How I can access the Reports?

I have also set up a Build configuration. In the tfs event viewer, I can read, that the build service http://COMPUTERNAME:9191/Build/v5.0/Services successfully registered.
But this url seems also not correct. But the buildservice is running.

And I have another problem with accessing the tfs web-interface.
From machines outside in the internet, I am able to access the tfs webinterface with the dns name of the machine like http://www.ourdomain.net:8080/tfs
But on the TFS server itself, I cannot. I can only access by the machines ip-address like http://11.12.13.14:8080/tfs
Using the dns name, I cannot log on, the provided credential is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

TFS queries reporting services and uses the URL's that it reports.

You can find the correct URL's if you open the Reporting Services Configuration console on the box it runs on. RS no longer uses IIS so you will not find anything in there.

It sounds like someone has changed the reporting services url since tfs was configured.

Answer (score 0):

Update your hosts file with the correct IP address for computer names.